# CSS top and bottom aligned

Tags: css, height, positioning

Trying to achieve this with relative/absolute positioning and floating

```
                 Col1                         Col2
------------------------------------------------------------
-  H1 Content aligned to top          - Some Content       -
-                                     -                    -
-                                     -                    -
-                                     -                    -
-                                     -                    -
-                                     -                    -
-                                     -                    -
- Some other content aligned to bot   -                    -
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Col2 drives the height of Col1

I either don't get the height in col1 or col2 ends up overlapping Col1 when i use absolute pos on the items within Col1

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste your css into the body of your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I have is with a fixed-height container:

```
<div id="news">
  <div class="news-panel" id="left-news">
    <h2>Side Header</h2>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-news">
    <h2>Side Footer</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="news-panel" id="right-news">
    Main Content
  </div>
</div>

div#news { margin: 0px auto; position: relative; width: 895px; height: 208px; border: 1px solid gray; }
div#news div.news-panel { position: absolute; top: 0; }
div#news div#footer-news { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
div#news div#left-news { left: 0; margin-right: 60px; width: 390px; border: 1px solid red; }
div#news div#right-news { width: 437px; right: 0px; }
```

sort of works although I'd hoped not to specify a height - here it is working (see the "What's happening" section): [AgileApps](http://www.agileapps.co.uk/)